# How to include moai in lua code for running it using luajit?

Tags: lua

I'm running moai from ubuntu for some simulation purposes.

I have a lua script that is executed using luaJIT.

Now I want to run a simulation written based on moai from within this script.

As of now, i can run the simulation like this : **moai sim.lua**

I want to see if i can do it lie this : **luajit sim.lua** ?

Is there a way to include moai just like other modules (require 'moai') and start using it ?

Thanks.